Question About the Proof of Proposition 4.4.6 in *Measure Theory* by Donald Cohn
I am self-studying Measure Theory by Donald Cohn. I got confused by some steps of his proof of the follow proposition:

Proposition 4.4.6$\quad$ The functions $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that can be written in the form
$$
F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^xf(t)dt\tag6
$$
for some $f$ in $\mathscr{L}^1(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}),\lambda,\mathbb{R})$ are exactly the absolutely continuous functions of finite variation that vanish at $-\infty$.


Proof$\quad$ First suppose that $f$ belongs to $\mathscr{L}^1(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}),\lambda,\mathbb{R})$ and that $F$ arises from $f$ through $(6)$. Then signed measure $\mu$ defined by $\mu(A)=\int_Afd\lambda$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$, and $F=F_{\mu}$; hence $F$ is of finite variation, is absolutely continuous, and vanishes at $-\infty$.
Now suppose that $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is of finite variation, is absolutely continuous, and vanishes at $-\infty$. Then there is a finite signed measure $\mu$ such that $F=F_{\mu}$, and $\mu\ll\lambda$. If $f=\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}$, then $(6)$ holds at each $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

My Question

In the first paragraph of the proof, why $\int_Afd\lambda$ defines a signed measure $\mu$? And why is $\mu\ll\lambda$? And why is $F=F_{\mu}$?
In the second paragraph of the proof, I couldn't understand why it is true that "If $f=\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}$, then $(6)$ holds at each $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$".

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out! Thank you very much in advance!


Definition$\quad$ Suppose that $\mu$ is a finite signed measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. Define a function $F_{\mu}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by letting
\begin{align}
    F_{\mu}(x) = \mu((-\infty,x])\tag1
\end{align}
hold at each $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$.


You probable need to review Radon Nikodym, Hahn decomposition, etc.

About (1): you can just verify that it satisfies the definition of a measure. Are you having difficulty verifying this? It's absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$ because if $\lambda(A) = 0$, then the integral $\int_A f d \lambda = 0$ as well, so it implies that $\mu(A) = 0.$
About question (2), I feel like you have a typo in equation (6). Are you sure it's not supposed to be $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) d \lambda(t)?$

Use comments to the question to ask for clarification.

I think you are right, it should mean $\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)d\lambda(t)$. And an $\mathscr{A}$-measurable function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies $\mu(A)=\int_Afd\lambda$ for each $A$ in $\mathscr{A}$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu$ with respect to $\lambda$ and is denoted by $\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}$, given $\mu$ a finite signed measure and $\lambda$ $\sigma$-finite. So question 2 falls into the definition. Is this what you mean?

yeah i'd say that question 2 is basically by definition
